order of list of elements located on a page keep changing on every click in selenium java
I located elements of languages displayed on google search page. I stored them in a list and iterated through the elements and tried to click one by one. But when I click the first element(link), the order of elements shuffles. when selenium tries to iterate through the next element and clicks it, it shows stale element exception. How to handle this situation?
We can find the available language below search input box.

Remember you're using a real browser here.  Once you click on a link, the original page is totally gone.  You can't continue iterating it.  What you'll need to do is extract all of the links into a list, and then go back and click those links one by one.

Thank you @Tim Robert for your reply.
is the below code right?
List elements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='SIvCob']//child::a"));
for(int i=0;i<elements.size();i++)
{
driver.navigate().back();
elements.get(i).click();
}

while iterating through a webelement reference array like that you should avoid doing any actions that would cause the DOM to change/update. (all references would go stale) You can instead get attribute of href, and then iterate through a list of hrefs using .get(href)

As long as WebElement is an object that doesn't depend on the page being live, that should work.  Otherwise, you may need to pull the URLs from the element and store them as strings.
